# How can I make Distribution files using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I want to distribute the installer package to my clients. Please anybody provide me details information about how can I make setup.exe file for my visual studio 2008 projects. If I am failed to provide any necessary info please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this is written for C#, the tutorial should work fine in VB.NET as well, if that's what you're using.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic58021.htm

Comment: It was a very very good tutorial. +1 for you. but friend, When I am going to install my project on the machine that have no .net framework then it tries to download the framework from the internet. But all of my clients may have no internet connections. Is there any way to provide the framework with my installation files?

Comment: I think this link can be helpful for my other friends who face the same problem as me.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77z6b8tz.aspx

Comment: Very very very very much thanks to dear rwmnau. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2008, add a new project.  Then click "Other Project Types" and Setup and Deployment underneath that.  You can then pick "Setup Wizard" this will guide you through creating a setup.exe and an MSI installer. This can then be built just like any other project, so when you make a change to your project, you can rebuild the setup.

Comment: the problem is when I want to install the project that is made by using your guideline to my client machine, it says that .NET Framework 3.5 is required. But I want to make such a setup file that will automatically install all the requirements because my client may have no internet connections.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an installer package, do the following:

1. Go to File -> Add New Project
2. Select Setup Project from "Setup and Deployment Projects"

From here you can add your files and when you compile it will generate an MSI file.

Comment: Please see the comment which I wrote for dear taylonr's solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a web server, i would publish your file using clickonce.  This way anytime you make a change your users will automatically get the updates.  To do so, right click the main project that you want to expose and click on the publish tab.

Comment: but friend my client may have no internet connection always.